# warning remove database

Tags: mysql, database, qt

my code show this next warning:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection ‘qt_sql_default_connection’ 
is still in  use, all queries will cease to work
```

This is my code the connection with data base is fine:

```
QSqlDatabase database::db()
{
    return m_db;
}

bool database::connect()
{
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    m_db.setDatabaseName("aaaa");
    m_db.setHostName("192.168.xxx.xxx");
    m_db.setUserName("xx");
    m_db.setPassword("xxxx");
    m_db.setPort(1234);

    return m_db.open();
}

void database::close()
{
    QString connection;
    connection = m_db.connectionName();
    m_db.close();
    m_db.removeDatabase(connection);
}
```

m_db is define as:

```
 QSqlDatabase m_db;
```

and my test is:

```
database db;
qDebug() << "CONNECT: " << db.connect();
db.close();
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After you closed it, `m_db` still holds a reference to the database you configured in `connect()`.

You can reset `m_db` by assigning a default constructed `QSqlDatabase`:

```
void database::close()
{
    QString connection;
    connection = m_db.connectionName();
    m_db.close();
    m_db = QSqlDatabase();
    m_db.removeDatabase(connection);
}
```

Comment: Of course this had to happen to me Friday late and on release date... I was convinced that after calling close() all references to the connection are gone! Not intuitive at all...  

@alexisdm I owe you like 10 beers ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
void database::close()
{
    QString connection;
    connection = m_db.connectionName();
    m_db = QSQlDatabase();
    //m_db.close();
    m_db.removeDatabase(connection);
}
```

try this it will work..

Answer (score 1):

Adding an additional scope does the same trick:

```
QString connectionName;
bool ok = false;

{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(databaseType);
    connectionName = db.connectionName();
    db.setHostName(hostname);
    db.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    db.setUserName(userName);
    db.setPassword(password);
    ok = db.open();
    db.close();
} 

QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(connectionName);
return ok;
```